# Create sparse graph from matrix

Tags: matlab, mupad

I have a large but sparse graph that I want to display with MuPAD. The graph is denoted in Matlab as a sparse squared matrix of edge weights.

When using [`Graph::createGraphFromMatrix(m)`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/graph-creategraphfrommatrix.html), I am unable to create anything but fully connected graphs. I tried with values of `0`, `NaN`/`undefined` and `Inf` for missing edges, but that only changed the weight of the resulting edges, but did not make them disappear.

Comment: have you tired using the more general constructor [`Graph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/graph.html)?

Comment: I have, but it forces me to represent the graph as node list, edge list and edge weight list. I tried that, but I was getting stuck on that route as well (MuPAD telling me I have duplicate edges when I don't. I checked with unique in Matlab.). I am now investigating graphviz...